# Setting the NSImage of a NSImageView from a NSURL

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

Okay, so I'm a newbie trying to write a practice app where you click a button, an `NSOpenPanel` appears, you select an image file, and the image gets displayed in an `NSImageView`.

I've got the open panel working okay, and it returns an `NSArray` of `NSURLs`. I avoided using filename paths as the Apple docs said it was depreciated. I then try to make an `NSImage` object using `initWithContentsOfURL`, and then try to setImage of the `NSImageView` to the new image.

Here's what I think are the relevant parts of the implementation...

```
   - (IBAction)openImage:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@ was clicked", sender);

    NSOpenPanel *panel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];

    if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
    {
        NSArray* selectedFile = [panel URLs];
        NSLog(@"%@ was selected", selectedFile[0]);
        NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:selectedFile[0]];

        [imageViewer setImage:theImage];
        }
    }
```

And from the header:

```
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageViewer;
    - (IBAction)openImage:(NSButton *)sender;
   @end
```

When I try to set the image, Xcode says there's `imageViewer` is undeclared, and wants to correct it to `_imageViewer`. I tried following its advice and ran it, but then the app just crashes once I select a file from the open panel so something is obviously still not right.

The `NSLog` lines shows the button was clicked, and shows the correct URL of the file selected, but I'm having issues setting the `NSImageView`. It's probably something really simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Use self.imageViewer or use _imageViewer. I suggest using self.imageViewer as it uses the setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I feel stupid now. I'm still learning stuff so I wasn't sure why it was freezing up until I noticed Xcode kept switching to the "Debug" panel, which clued me into what might be happening.

I figured out I accidentally clicked a line number, which apparently sets breakpoints for debugging. I also might have somehow clicked "Toggle global breakpoint state" in the bottom Debug area.

Because I selected the line where the `setImage` was, it looked like the app crashed/froze whenever it hit that line, but it actually just paused the app to allow me to look at what's going on with the app and debug it. I deselected the lines and turned off the global breakpoint state button and everything runs fine now.

A newbie coder mistake from somebody not used to working in an IDE. :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable `imageViewer` in your headers (`.h`) `interface` , for example:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     IBOutlet NSImageView *__weak imageViewer; 
}
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageViewer;
- (IBAction)openImage:(NSButton *)sender;
@end
```

Then in your class (`.m`) just synthesize the variable:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize imageViewer;

...
```

Since you hadn't `declared` the variable in the `interface` you were receiving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
- (IBAction)openImage:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@ was clicked", sender);

    NSOpenPanel *panel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];

    if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
    {
        NSArray* selectedFile = [panel URLs];
        NSLog(@"%@ was selected", selectedFile[0]);
        NSURL *url = (NSURL *)selectedFile[0];
        NSString *filePath = [url absoluteString];
        NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        [imageViewer setImage:theImage];
        }
    }
```